# How effectively extracts value from function (python) and pass to context (Django)

Tags: python, django, function

I have function in seperate django file `function.py`.

My function consists of lenthy calculations whiuch i then pass to views. there are functions inside the main function `a()`. This is how to pass value ( this is shortest version to pass you idea os what i am trying to say).

```
def a():

    x=3
    y=4
    z=6


    def b():
        x1=x+1
        return x1

    def c():
        y1=y+1
        return y1

    def d():
         z1=z+1


   return b(), c(), d()



def home(request):

abc=a()

context={'value1':abc[0],'value2':abc[1],'value3':abc[2],}

print(value1)
```

This how i pass value. Is this efefctive way or there are more efficient ways to pass values form the function as as so far i manually have to pass to the `context in views` through indexing as i did. What is your recomendation to ease my work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If abc returns three values, then I would stick with the code you've got.

If `abc` returned many values (or an arbitrary number of values), then you could use a dictionary comprehension.

```
context = {'value%s' % i: j for i, j in enumerate(abc, 1)}
```

This wouldn't be more efficient in terms of performance of the view, but it might make the code easier to read/maintain.

Comment: so to return the first value in html page ?  value%s[0] ?

Comment: your code does not work it says : invalid syntax 'for' you see my ocntext have other values not from the function a()

Comment: The dictionary comprehension is creating a dictionary that contains keys `value1`, `value2`, `value3` for every item in `abc`. So you would do `{{ value1 }}` or `{{ value2}}` in the template.

Comment: The code does work. For the example you give, replace `abc = a()` with `abc = [2, 4, 6]`. Then the dictionary comprehension returns the dict `{'value1': 2, 'value2': 4, 'value3': 6, 'value4': 8}`.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, I don't think you should try to add `abc` as individual keys. Why not do `context = {'abc': abc, 'other_value': 'potato'}`. Then in the template you can do `{{ potato }}` and `{{ abc.0 }}`, `{{ abc.1 }}` and so on.

Comment: my context has ={'years':year10,'value%s' % i: j for i, j in enumerate(abc, 1)  } and when i insert your code it does not work . I do not know what is the problem.

Comment: In your original question there weren't any other values in the dict. You would have to do something like `{'years':year10, **{'value%s' % i: j for i, j in enumerate(abc, 1)}}`. But I think I prefer the approach of adding `'abc': abc` to the context.

Answer (score 2):

Hard-coding indices is generally considered un-Pythonic. To avoid it, you can zip the names with the tuple returned by the function and then passed the zipped sequence of tuples to the `dict` constructor:

```
context = dict(zip(('value1', 'value2', 'value3'), a()))
```

If you have additional context variables, you can instead unpack the above in a dict literal with the other items:

```
context = {'other1': 1, 'other2': 2, **dict(zip(('value1', 'value2', 'value3'), a()))}
```

Comment: how to return the value1 in html? just write value1?

Comment: You can use a Django template expression such as `{{ value1 }}`.

Comment: your code does not work my context contains other values not from function . How to make it workable in this case as your way does not work